# If not multiple conditions with certain values

Tags: php, if-statement

I have 2 variables:

1) `$key` : this variable can either contain the word `Unknown` or not.

2) `$val` : this variable can contain `0,0` or some other values

I want to run a script in case that `$key` not containing `Unknown` AND `$val` not equal `0,0`. So skip the script if BOTH variables have the above mentioned values ONLY.

So I have the following code:

```
if(strpos($key, 'Unknown') !== false && $val == '0,0') {
   /* do nothing! */
}
else {
   /* continue script */
}
```

So is there a better way to achieve the above without having this empty if condition

Comment: if (negate condition or other condition )

Comment: What's your definition of better? More performant? More readable? As it stands, it's very opinionated and hence off-topic

Comment: @k0pernikus I think it doesn't make sense to have if something, do nothing, else, do this

Comment: @bassxzero can you please explain more or give an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSamuel You could instead of doing nothing do an early `return` (or if within a loop a `continue`), and then you can remove the else statement and just have to code go on normally. You might even depending on the use case throw an exception and handle that in a try-catch-block.

Comment: Can you clarify the scope on how you execute that code block? What happens within the else block?

Comment: @k0pernikus the else simply runs other code like echo and such

Comment: Depending on what exactly that "other code" is supposed to be doing, you might want to handle it differently. That's why your comment is not that helpful in order to suggest you a certain approach, though it indicates that you also maybe should think a bit more about separation of concerns. As it stands, I recommend going with the early return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply negate the conditional statements.

```
if(strpos($key, 'Unknown') === false || $val != '0,0') {
    /* continue script */
}
```

Comment: Now if `$key` not equal `Unknown`, the script will not continue :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Damn double negatives, the update should do the desired behaviour.

Comment: Surprisingly this worked! So a double negative check actually leads to both conditions get treated as a one unit even though i have the double pipes `||`?

Comment: The basic logic is if you negative the conditions and the clause that binds them you effectively negate the question you're asking. E.G. Instead of saying if both of these things are true do nothing otherwise do something, you can say if either of these are false then do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can exit the code block early:

```
if(strpos($key, 'Unknown') !== false && $val == '0,0') {
   return;
}

/* continue script */
```